# No 'Makefile' created KAMENSKY/Text-Bidi-2.11.tar.gz

Tags: linux, centos, perl, cpan

I am trying to install following perl module via cpan on centos 6.x but unfortunately getting error. Please advise to solve.

- Text::Bidi
- Version: 0.03
- Usage: Label batch PDF

***CPAN***

/usr/bin/cpan script version 1.9, CPAN.pm version 1.9402

***PERL***

This is perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi

***Error***

```
[root@csc ~]# cpan Text::Bidi
CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.20)
Going to read '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Fri, 26 Feb 2016 08:17:02 GMT
Running install for module 'Text::Bidi'
CPAN: YAML loaded ok (v0.72)
Running make for K/KA/KAMENSKY/Text-Bidi-2.11.tar.gz
CPAN: Digest::SHA loaded ok (v5.47)
CPAN: Compress::Zlib loaded ok (v2.021)
Checksum for /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/K/KA/KAMENSKY/Text-Bidi-2.11.tar.gz ok
CPAN: Archive::Tar loaded ok (v1.58)
Text-Bidi-2.11
Text-Bidi-2.11/Changes
Text-Bidi-2.11/t
Text-Bidi-2.11/t/ucd.t
Text-Bidi-2.11/LICENSE
Text-Bidi-2.11/INSTALL
Text-Bidi-2.11/dist.ini
Text-Bidi-2.11/META.yml
Text-Bidi-2.11/cpanfile
Text-Bidi-2.11/MANIFEST
Text-Bidi-2.11/private.c
Text-Bidi-2.11/misc
Text-Bidi-2.11/misc/bidi
Text-Bidi-2.11/t/shape.t
Text-Bidi-2.11/META.json
Text-Bidi-2.11/weaver.ini
Text-Bidi-2.11/Makefile.PL
Text-Bidi-2.11/t/known.txt
Text-Bidi-2.11/MANIFEST.SKIP
Text-Bidi-2.11/bin
Text-Bidi-2.11/bin/fribidi.pl
Text-Bidi-2.11/swig
Text-Bidi-2.11/swig/fribidi.i
Text-Bidi-2.11/t/00-version.t
Text-Bidi-2.11/t/BidiTest.txt
Text-Bidi-2.11/t/00-compile.t
Text-Bidi-2.11/lib/Text
Text-Bidi-2.11/lib/Text/Bidi.pm
Text-Bidi-2.11/t/BidiTest.txt.gz
Text-Bidi-2.11/xt/author
Text-Bidi-2.11/xt/author/critic.t
Text-Bidi-2.11/t/00-report-prereqs.t
Text-Bidi-2.11/xt/release
Text-Bidi-2.11/xt/release/distmeta.t
Text-Bidi-2.11/lib/Text/Bidi
Text-Bidi-2.11/lib/Text/Bidi/Array.pm
Text-Bidi-2.11/t/00-report-prereqs.dd
Text-Bidi-2.11/xt/release/pod-syntax.t
Text-Bidi-2.11/lib/Text/Bidi/private.pm
Text-Bidi-2.11/xt/release/portability.t
Text-Bidi-2.11/xt/release/pod-coverage.t
Text-Bidi-2.11/xt/release/test-version.t
Text-Bidi-2.11/lib/Text/Bidi/Constants.pm
Text-Bidi-2.11/lib/Text/Bidi/Paragraph.pm
Text-Bidi-2.11/lib/Text/Bidi/Array
Text-Bidi-2.11/lib/Text/Bidi/Array/Byte.pm
Text-Bidi-2.11/lib/Text/Bidi/Array/Long.pm
Text-Bidi-2.11/xt/release/minimum-version.t
CPAN: File::Temp loaded ok (v0.22)

  CPAN.pm: Going to build K/KA/KAMENSKY/Text-Bidi-2.11.tar.gz

Package fribidi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `fribidi.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'fribidi' found
 at Makefile.PL line 13.

It seems that fribidi is missing. 

fribidi should be installed prior to the installation of this module.

No 'Makefile' created  KAMENSKY/Text-Bidi-2.11.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Make had some problems, won't test
Running make install
  Make had some problems, won't install
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toward the end it has these important lines:

```
It seems that fribidi is missing. 

fribidi should be installed prior to the installation of this module.
```

The perl module is an interface to fribidi, not a separate implementation.  You have to have this program installed on your machine before you build the perl module.

If you are sure you have it installed, then there are some additional configurations that might be necessary.